# Php Header command working in one file but not working on other

Tags: php, redirect, header

hye ,
My current Directory structure is like

1. Admin (index.php, country.php)
2. Classes(connection.php,login.php,country.php)
3. header.php
4. footer.php
5. index.php
6. includes(header.php,footer.php)

my problem is that on **webserver** when i am in **/admin/country.php** and add a country using form post method and action set to **/classes/country.php** my header statement "**Header("Location: ../Admin/country.php")**" is working ok but when i am on my index page in root directory and try to login with form action **"classes/login.php"** and on successful login i use **header("Location: ../Admin/index.php")** it never redirects but everything works fine my local server, i don't know whats the problem over here, Any help would be really appreciated, 
I have searched this forum and others and tried to use the techniques they have told but nothing is working

my index page [index.php](http://asad.thexchanger.com/)

my Admin Section [Admin/Country.php](http://asad.thexchanger.com/Admin/country.php)

my login.php script is below

```
<?php 
        ob_start();
        include_once("classes/connection.php");
?>



<?php

    class login
    {
        public static function validateLogin($userName,$password)
        {
            if(isset($userName) && isset($password))
            {
                $connection  = dbconnection::getConnection();
                $query = "Select * from tbllogin Where loginID ='" . $userName .
                "' and password = '" . $password . "'";

                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $rowsAffected =  mysql_affected_rows();

                if($rowsAffected==0)
                {

                        //header("Location: ../index.php/");
                        //exit();
                        return false;
                }
                else
                {

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        //working

                        $role = $row["role"];
                        if($role == "Admin")
                        {

                            //header('Location: ../Admin/index.php');
                            //exit();
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //echo "hello";
                            //header("Location: ../index.php/");
                            //exit();
                            return false;
                        }

                        //return $result;
                        //header("Location: ../index.php");

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //header("Location: ../index.php/");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }


?>


<?php

    if(isset($_POST["btnSumbit"]))
    {
        $isValid = login::validateLogin($_POST["userID"],$_POST["password"]);
        if(isset($isValid))
        {
            if($isValid ==true)
            {
                $host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                $uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
                $extra = 'Admin/index.php';
                header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }

    ob_end_flush();
```

?>

Comment: Please show some of your actual code. It will help the community to be able to help you.

Comment: What error do you get when it does not redirect? have you got errors and warnings turned on so you can see what the problem is?

Comment: @anigel -> i am not getting any error , it just wont redirect when i login from index.php with form action classes/login.php and then in classes/login.php i call header("Location: ../Admin/index.php") and it won't work , but when i am in "/Admin/country.php" and call a form action ../classes/country.php and then use header("Location:../Admin/country.php") it redirect as expected !!e

Answer (score 0):

Don't use header redirects with relative paths. You should redirect to the front end URL path or absolute paths.

It's possible that your "classes/login.php" is an included file into "index.php" -- so you're actually trying to step out of the web server directory - which is why it works locally but not on the server.

Comment: for the source code please download from here : https://www.box.com/s/lst2pqpvqvw0vi5xi6c0

Comment: **can you please tell me how should i redirect to front end url path or absolute path **